# How can you format a persisted column as a padded integer string [SQL Server 2008]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, formula, persisted-column

What formula would I use in a persisted column so that I can add the two columns below together, the first must be padded to 5 characters:

- ID (INT)
- RefNum (STRING)

I went for `format(ID,"00000") & RefNum`, but it doesn't work, any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) + RefNum
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD FormattedColumn AS RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) + RefNum PERSISTED
```

Basically, convert the `ID` to a `VARCHAR(5)`, prepend it with `00000` and then grab the five right-most characters.